# Navigation on ViewModel in MVVM Light in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light

I have a Xamarin.froms app in MVVM Light, i want to open another page on button click, but i only want to use this method of Page class

```
page.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage())
```

How to send "Page" class as reference on ViewModel class.

Answer (score 2):

There are variety of ways to do this.

Easy way:

- Pass the Page as a constructor parameter of View Model.

The useful way:

- Write a Navigation Service. This can extend from a Content Page like this:

  ```
  public class NavigationService : ContentPage
  {
          public static INavigation Navigation
          {
              get {
                  return Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
              }
          }

          public static IReadOnlyList<Page> NavigationStack () {
                  return Navigation.NavigationStack;
          }
  }
  ```

Now you can use this Service in your ViewModel like this:

```
Page lastPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.Last;
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML code

```
<Button Text="Help" Command="{Binding NavigateHelpPage}"/>
```

MVVM Hierarchical page navigation in Xamarin.forms

```
public ICommand NavigateHelpPage { get; }
    
private async Task NavigateToHelpPage()
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HelpPage());
}
```

Inside Constructor:

```
NavigateHelpPage = new Command(async () => await NavigateToHelpPage());
```

MainPage you can set like :

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Dashboard.DashboardPage());
```